# Chrome DevTools - Hide or Collapse Preflight

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In my Google Chrome DevTools, preflight requests are combined together as one
"POST + Preflight"

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Devtools]

However, on other machines, each POST + Preflight are separated into two, so for the above example, you would find 4 entries:

- Preflight
- POST
- Preflight
- POST

What is the setting in DevTools to combine the requests together like the screenshot above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, just have to filter it by "Fetch/XHR". Additionally we added the "Method" column as that's useful to have.